# Magento2 - How to validate image width and height in admin form

Tags: magento2, admin, adminform

I have created a custom module for image upload in magento2 admin form. How to validate the image width and height.

Any help on the issue please?

Comment: Fixed the issue by adding the validation condition in the save controller

Comment: how are you adding your fields? via UI

Comment: Added fields in ui component xml file

Comment: In that case as @user78358 stated you will need to add a validation condition to the save controller which validates the width and height and if they do not match then returning back an exception